# How does super.render() call this method?

Tags: java, libgdx, inheritance

Today I was experimenting with adding different screens with `Scene2d` in `libgdx` and while doing so I became confused how `super.render()` in my `render()` method from my starter class (`MyGdxGame`) called `render()` in my `PlayScreen()` class. Basically I understand you use `super` to call methods, fields, invoke a super class constructor etc... however I don't see how my `Main class` witch `extends Game` is a subclass/derived class of my `PlayScreen class` witch simply `implements Screen`. In short I don't see how those two classes are related so that `super.render()` in `MyGdxGame` class can call `render()` in my `PlayScreen` class.

Also I looked at the API and `Screen` implements `ScreenAdapter` and `Game` implements `ApplicationListener` but I still don't see how that connects.

Starter class:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends Game {
    Game game;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        game = this;
        setScreen(new MainMenu(game));
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();
    }

    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
    }

    public void pause() {
        super.pause();
    }
}
```

PlayScreen class:

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {
    private static Player player;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    GameControls x;
    CollisionManager collisionManager;
    ArrayList<Tree> trees;
    Iterator itr;
    Enemy enemy;
    Animations animation;
    Game game;
    MainMenu mainMenu;

    public PlayScreen(Game game, MainMenu mainMenu) {
        this.game = game;
        this.mainMenu = mainMenu;
    }
// more code ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDE of choice should have a way for you to navigate to the source for a specified class.  For IntelliJ IDEA try moving your cursor to the Game class name that MyGdxGame extends and pressing CTRL + B.  That should take you to the source for Game.  Take a look at the override for render() that Game implements.

```
@Override
public void render () {
    if (screen != null) screen.render(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
}
```

It calls into the active screen object (set previously by setScreen(Screen)).  That's how they are linked. :)

You can always reference the git repository as well, if that's easier for you in the future: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx